# Discrete mathematics - counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Students need to answer 8 out of 10 questions in mathematics exam. In how many ways can a student choose 8 questions if the first three questions are mandatory?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: So... the first three questions are mandatory.  Among the remaining **seven** questions (*10-3=7 questions that are not mandatory*), the student still needs to **choose** another **five** more questions (*8-3=5 questions still needing to be answered*).

Comment: @Baba 7C3 is too large.

Comment: I had a midterm where I had to answer three out of four questions. Needless to say, I did not do the second one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the first three questions are mandatory, we need not care about them, and the question simplifies to figuring out how many ways can students choose $5$ questions from $7$ questions. The obvious answer to this question is $7\choose 5$. To understand some of the reasoning that goes on, you can consider it this way:

1. The number of ways that $7$ questions can be permuted is equal to $7!$
2. The number of ways that $5$ questions can be selected from these permutations is $\frac{7!}{2!} = 7\times6\times5\times4\times3$. However, this preserves the various permutations of these $5$ selected questions, and in this case it's clear that these need not be selected.
3. The number of permutations of $5$ numbers is $5!$, and so dividing by $5!$ will get rid of the permutations to yield $\frac{7!}{2!5!}$ solutions.

The quantity $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is often represented as $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}$$

And our solution becomes $7\choose 5$.